# How to pass a prototype function to my object without needing to call it?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I am creating a script that registers products and already assigns each one unique code, this code is generated through a `codeGenerator` function.

I would like to know how I could pass this function as a prototype, without the need to call the function to assign my codes, more or less this way:

```
Vacuum = registerProduct('LG - Vacuum Cleaner 3000','appliances','Super smart vacuum cleaner sucking: water, dust and souls','300')
```

Returning an object:

```
APPLIANCES: Product {name: "LG - Vacuum Cleaner 3000", category: "appliances", description: "Super smart vacuum cleaner sucking: water, dust and souls", price: "R $: 300.00", code: "API- 01 "}
```

I get that same exit more this way:

```js
const productsRegistered = {}

console.log(productsRegistered.length);
const Product = function( name, category, description, price, code) {
    
    this.name = name
    this.category = category
    this.description = description
    this.price = 'R$: ' + price + '.00' 
    this.code = codeGenerator(this.category)
}

function codeGenerator(productCategory) {   
    let productCode = ''
            
    if (productCategory.length <= 3){
        productCode = productCategory
    } else { 
        productCode = sliceWords(productCategory)
    }
    
    if (typeof productList === 'undefined') {
        productCode += '-01'
    } else { 
        productCode += '-0' + productList.length + 1
    } 
    return productCode
}

function registerProduct( name, category, description, price ) {
    productsRegistered[category.toUpperCase()] =  new Product(name,category,description,price)
}

function sliceWords(word) {
    code = ''

    for(let n = 0; n <= 5; n += 2) {
        code += word[n].toUpperCase()
    } return code
}

Computer = registerProduct('HP - ALL IN ONE','Computers and Laptops','HP Computer Entel Core i10','1500')
Vacuum = registerProduct('LG - Vacuum Cleaner 3000','appliances','Super smart vacuum cleaner sucking: water, dust and souls','300')

console.log(productsRegistered);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is change the `productsRegistered` from an array to an object. If you have an array, the items aren't visible when you log them, because they're not on array index properties.

Because `registerProduct` doesn't return anything, you shouldn't assign the return value to a variable - instead, examine the `productsRegistered` object.

```js
const productsRegistered = {};

const Product = function( name, category, description, price, code) {
    
    this.name = name
    this.category = category
    this.description = description
    this.price = 'R$: ' + price + '.00' 
    this.code = codeGenerator(productsRegistered)
}

function codeGenerator(productList) {   
    let productCode = ''

    for (product in productList)  {
        let productCategory = productList[product].category
            
        if (productCategory.length <= 3){
            productCode = productCategory
        } else { 
            productCode = sliceWords(productCategory)
        }

        if (productList.length === 0) {
            productCode += '-01'
        } else { 
            productCode += '-0' + productList.length + 1
        }
    }  return productCode
}

function registerProduct( name, category, description, price ) {
    productsRegistered[category.toUpperCase()] =  new Product(name,category,description,price)
}

function sliceWords(word) {
    code = ''

    for(let n = 0; n <= 5; n += 2) {
        code += word[n].toUpperCase()
    } return code
}

registerProduct('HP - ALL IN ONE','Computers and Laptops','HP Computer Entel Core i10','1500')
registerProduct('LG - Vacuum Cleaner 3000','appliances','Super smart vacuum cleaner sucking: water, dust and souls','300')

console.log(productsRegistered);
```

Or, if you do want the product to be visible in the `productsRegistered` object *and* in the return value of calling `registerProduct`, save the instantiated Product in a variable so you can both assign it to the object and return it:

```js
const productsRegistered = {};

const Product = function(name, category, description, price, code) {

  this.name = name
  this.category = category
  this.description = description
  this.price = 'R$: ' + price + '.00'
  this.code = codeGenerator(productsRegistered)
}

function codeGenerator(productList) {
  let productCode = ''

  for (product in productList) {
    let productCategory = productList[product].category

    if (productCategory.length <= 3) {
      productCode = productCategory
    } else {
      productCode = sliceWords(productCategory)
    }

    if (productList.length === 0) {
      productCode += '-01'
    } else {
      productCode += '-0' + productList.length + 1
    }
  }
  return productCode
}

function registerProduct(name, category, description, price) {
  const product = new Product(name, category, description, price);
  productsRegistered[category.toUpperCase()] = product;
  return product;
}

function sliceWords(word) {
  code = ''

  for (let n = 0; n <= 5; n += 2) {
    code += word[n].toUpperCase()
  }
  return code
}

const computer = registerProduct('HP - ALL IN ONE', 'Computers and Laptops', 'HP Computer Entel Core i10', '1500')
const vacuum = registerProduct('LG - Vacuum Cleaner 3000', 'appliances', 'Super smart vacuum cleaner sucking: water, dust and souls', '300')

console.log(productsRegistered);
console.log(computer);
```

If you want each value of the `productsRegistered` object to be an array instead of an object, then create the array at the property if it doesn't exist there yet, then push to it:

```js
const productsRegistered = {};

const Product = function(name, category, description, price, code) {

  this.name = name
  this.category = category
  this.description = description
  this.price = 'R$: ' + price + '.00'
  this.code = codeGenerator(this.category)
}

function codeGenerator(productCategory) {
  let productCode = ''

  if (productCategory.length <= 3) {
    productCode = productCategory
  } else {
    productCode = sliceWords(productCategory)
  }

  if (typeof productList === 'undefined') {
    productCode += '-01'
  } else {
    productCode += '-0' + productList.length + 1
  }
  return productCode
}


function registerProduct(name, category, description, price) {
  const product = new Product(name, category, description, price);
  const key = category.toUpperCase();
  if (!productsRegistered[key]) {
    productsRegistered[key] = [];
  }
  productsRegistered[key].push(product);
  return product;
}

function sliceWords(word) {
  code = ''

  for (let n = 0; n <= 5; n += 2) {
    code += word[n].toUpperCase()
  }
  return code
}

const computer = registerProduct('HP - ALL IN ONE', 'Computers and Laptops', 'HP Computer Entel Core i10', '1500')
const vacuum = registerProduct('LG - Vacuum Cleaner 3000', 'appliances', 'Super smart vacuum cleaner sucking: water, dust and souls', '300')

console.log(productsRegistered);
console.log(computer);
```

Comment: I'm going to say your answer is well intended, but from a design standpoint it usually doesn't make sense to use unknown Object properties. How will you get them later? Always loop? Just helping OP.

Comment: It's the second parameter passed to `registerProduct`. This appears to be the data structure he wants, perhaps his real code is saving that second parameter in a variable first, or something like that.

Comment: Perhaps you are correct. OP would have to know those are the properties to look for without looping for optimal performance, though. Also, I'm pretty sure OP would want an Array of Objects for each category.

Comment: @CertainPerformance It would be a good idea to turn my array into an object but I did some tests and the problem is that this way I will not be able to use lenght, and my object keeps returning incorrect codes taking the category of my predecessor object

Comment: @luismatheus Your current `codeGenerator` function doesn't make much sense. You iterate over every key in `productList`, but the only calculations that matter are the ones in the final iteration, because `productCode` gets reassigned every time.

Comment: @luismatheus If you want each value of the `productsRegistered` object to be an array instead of an object, then create the array at the property if it doesn't exist there yet, then push to it

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you very much for the tips, there were a lot of inconsistencies in my code, I just can't put it with solution because my main objective is to use the prototype.

Comment: @luismatheus Do you mean that you can't have any standalone functions, they all need to be on the prototype? No matter where the functions are, if the functions exist, if you want them to run, you *will* have to call them - regardless of whether they're standalone or on the prototype or somewhere else